# Ubuntu 14.04 Slow download speed

Tags: downloads, download-speed

I was downloading a pdf file once, its size is only around 1 MB, and I've noticed how slow the download speed is, varying from 10 kB/s to 3 kB/s and it then becomes 0 kB/s. How can I solve this. My laptop is in dual-boot, when I use Windows it's not slow.

Answer (score 0):

There could be other background applications using network connection at that point of time. 
Check your proxy(if you use one) and firewall settings. It could be due to an error on the server which stored the file